# Convert Enum into another Enum

Tags: c#, enums

I have two enums:

```
public enum Fruits
{
    Apple = 1,
    Banana = 2,
    Strawberry = 3,
    Blueberry = 4
}

public enum FruitsCombined
{
    Apple = 1,
    Banana = 2,
    Berries = 0  //Strawberry and Blueberry combined
}
```

I have a Combobox, which is bound to the `FruitsCombined` enum, but in the background, when I select `Berries`, I want to say it's 3 and 4 from the `Fruits` enum.

How can I do this?

For example, I want to replace this for a better way, with the two enums:

```
if ((int)cboFilterFruitType.SelectedValue == 0)
{
    order = order.FindAll(o => o.FruitID == 3 || o.FruitID == 4);
}
else
{
    order = order.FindAll(o => o.FruitID == (int) cboFilterFruitType.SelectedValue);
}
```

Comment: Use [`Flags`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8480/43846)?

Comment: You should not use `0` as a value for any meaningful enum value because that's the value of `default(TEnum)`. So you should change `Berries = 0` to `Berries = 3` - or better-yet: `Berries = 7` (because `7 == 3 | 4`).

Comment: Are you using WinForms, WPF, or some other UI framework?

Comment: I use Winforms.

Comment: Best way is make enum values a power of 2 :    Apple = 1, Banana = 2, Strawberry = 4, Blueberry = 8.  Then berries will be 12 (8 + 4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`flags`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=net-6.0) enums:

```
[Flags]
public enum Fruits
{
    Apple = 1,
    Banana = 2,
    Strawberry = 4,
    Blueberry = 8
}

public enum FruitsCombined
{
    Apple = 1,
    Banana = 2,
    Berries = Fruits.Strawberry | Fruits.Blueberry //Strawberry and Blueberry combined
}
```

Now you can cast one to the other:

```
FruitsCombined fruitCombined = FruitsCombined.Berries;
Fruits fruit = (Fruits)fruitCombined; // Fruits.Strawberry | Fruits.Blueberry
```

If you want to check if it's a berry you can use [`Enum.HasFlag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag?view=net-6.0):

```
bool isBerry = fruit.HasFlag(Fruits.Strawberry | Fruits.Blueberry);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over both enums you could combine the enums together using flags like suggested in the comments.

```cs
[Flags]
public enum Fruits
{
    None = 0,
    Apple = 1,
    Banana = 2,
    Strawberry = 4,
    Blueberry = 8,
    Berries = Strawberry | Blueberry
}
```

Then if you had code like this

```cs
var fruit = Fruits.Berries;
Console.WriteLine(fruit.HasFlag(Strawberry));
Console.WriteLine(fruit.HasFlag(Blueberry));
```

Both write lines would print true.

Answer (score 0):

as stuartd link says do something more like

change to powers of two

```
public enum Fruits
{
    Apple = 1,
    Banana = 2,
    Strawberry = 4,
    Blueberry = 8
}
```

Then you can use bitwise to represent any combo

var appBann = Fruits.Apple | Suits.Banana ;

or Berries  = Fruits.Strawberry | Suits.Blueberry

you can even have it as a enum

```
  public enum Fruits
    {
        Apple = 1,
        Banana = 2,
        Strawberry = 4,
        Blueberry = 8,
        Berries = Strawberry | Blueberry
    }
```

```
 order = order.FindAll(o => o.FruitID == (int)Fruits.Berries);
```